# /etc/resolv.conf is getting overwritten

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

I have set up my own bind9 DNS server and put into my `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
domain mydomain.local
```

and put the same content into `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`

still the dns fails once in a while and additional information (the ones from my hoster) are magically written into the `etc/resolv.conf`. Am I missing any service how manages this file and conflicts with bind9?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using DHCP, the DHCP server can tell you what resolvers to use. If you want to manually configure resolvers, I'd suggest manually configuring IP addresses as well. Otherwise, assuming the filesystem supports it, set the `/etc/resolv.conf` file immutable. (`chattr +i` on Linux.)

Comment: sure, I do not use any DHCP and even set, but I will try the immutable